# Oracle java SE runtime Env 8 - 111 instalation fail [installer blank screen][Windows]

Tags: java, windows

[image: blanc screen during install / uninstall java]

Hi,

java SE runtime Env 8 - 111

I get screen like that when I'm trying install or remove old versions of Java

Was trying to fix that in many ways:

1. - it is said that is because of AntiAliasing function of Nvidia card - Not true, after uninstaling display drivers, and using to delete all nvidia packages

http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html

there is no effects even on clean primary windows display driver

2. **rebuilding services, WMI, permissions to registry keys, default permissions to services, and system files by**

http://www.tweaking.com/

several times,

3. trying to install by internet setup, full package, 32bit, 64bit
4. system checked by several tools for viruses, malware, spyware, etc..
5. cleaning temp folders (system and user), browsers cache,
6. cleaning registry keys by CCleaner.
7. - yes, windows update works like a charm.... (like no windows update.. ; -)

I have also linux (Fedora)  system for programing, but it is for other purpose. So please don't make a comments in style "instal linux"...
I still need Windows 7 machine for php 5 & 7 MySQL/Postgres/M$ SQL and Android apps enviroment...

Comment: You tried downloading the installer from the [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) site and running it? Your screenshot is not from the installer, but from a website.

Comment: hi @andreas , yes, I explained that in point "3" of my tryings how to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for this issue is**

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-install-all-versions-of-net-framework-plus-hotfixes-with-aio-runtimes/

https://www.computerbase.de/downloads/systemtools/all-in-one-runtimes/?download

It removes all M$ Visual C++ Redist (a really big mess always) and replace them with curent fresh versions.

You can't keep them fresh just by M$ Windows update.

After that your Java Runtime Enviroment - will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the Java 8 install by installing silently.

An older Java 8u11 works to install but any newer versions won't install you will see a blank screen when trying to install.

To silently install:
Download Java 8 to your C:\ then run Navigate to the C:\ via cmd prompt
Enter the following command (using the name of the file you downloaded): jre-8u271-windows-i586.exe /s
Press Enter